# Cannot copy scripts from index.js to assets folder in react native

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

Everytime when I create and run a sample app in react native I'm getting this error "Unable to load scripts from assets index.android.bundle". So I tried this solution

1.mkdir assets with android/app/src/main

2.react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res

3.react-native run-android

But getting this error `Plugin 0 specified in "E:\\SampleReact\\node_modules\\babel-preset-react-native\\index.js" provided an invalid property of "default" (While processing preset: "E:\\SampleReact\\node_modules\\babel-preset-react-native\\index.js")`.Before this i was getting the error unable to find `Accessibility info` within react-native so i downgraded the RN version from 0.56 to 0.55.4.Then i tried but getting the above error.Stuck with this.Please help.The problem is that i just installed windows 10 so that i need to install all the dependencies(node,android studio, react-native, java sdk etc..) from the beginning.So please help.

Answer (score 0):

change your dev settings ip, if its emulator its like(10.0.2.2:8081), if device(yoursystemip:8081). try this it ll work

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I tried this but still getting the same.

Comment: else change the port number, if firewall is there, it might not work